# Weird subspace/equality-constrained LP problem/variant of change-making problem

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-programming

Assume that we have a set, $\mathscr{R}$ containing $m$-dimensional vectors. Solve
$$\sum_{i=1}^n c_i\leq\delta$$
$$\text{subject to } \sum_{i=1}^n r_i c_i=x^\prime \text{ for all }x^\prime$$
where
$0\leq c_i\leq \delta$, $r_i\in\mathscr{R}$, and $n=\left|\mathscr{R}\right|$.
Reducing to a linear algebra problem by noting that $x^\prime$ is a linear combination over $span\{r_i\}$,
$$Ax=b$$
where $A$ is $m \times n$ and has columns $r_1, r_2, \dots, r_n$, $x$ is an $n$-dimensional vector with $x_i=c_i$, and $b$ is an $m$-dimensional vector with $b_i=x^\prime_i$, and finding "nonnegative" $x$ such that the sum of its elements is less than $\delta$ (coincidentally, since we assume elements of $x$ are nonnegative, the problem also equates to minimizing its $L^1$-norm).

One simple linear algebra theorem pertinent to this is that $range(A)\subseteq\mathbb{R}^m$, with equality happening when the columns of $A$ form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^m$. There must be $m$ vectors in that basis, so $n\geq m$ in order for the "for all" part of the constraint to be satisfied. **In other words, I need to find an enumeration of linearly dependent $m$ vectors that spans $\mathbb{R}^m$ but also ensure that any vector in $\mathbb{R}^m$ can be represented as a linear combination of scalars whose sum is $\leq \delta$. The number of vectors in this set is $n\geq m$.** However, I don't know how to proceed from here. One thing that I thought about is to rewrite this problem into an LP problem with $m$ equality constraints and minimizing $c^T v$ where $v$ is $n$-dimensional and filled with 1's, but I don't know if that'd help honestly.

Is this question even solvable?

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to understand the question. Are you looking for the $c$ vector or $x$ vector? If you're looking for $c$, you're right that you can minimise $v^Tc$ such and then add all the $\leq \delta$ inequalitites to the constraints.

Comment: @marcelgoh the final goal is to figure out how to populate $\mathscr{R}$ with vectors such that the $\delta$ condition is always satisfied, and how many vectors (not all linearly independent) $\mathscr{R}$ should contain, i.e. $n$. In this context, $c=x$; $x$ is just a relabeling of $c$

Comment: Ahh okay, then yeah I can’t see any obvious LP formulation. Sorry, I hope someone has an answer for you!